# Template syntax error when rendering crispy-form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I use **semantic-ui** as template for **crispy-forms**. When trying to load the page it results in the following error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /forum/newpost/pqs53kqsbgsqd66pg0i60u-isjtvagbo4ii4q9/
>
> crispy tag's template_pack argument should be in ('bootstrap', 'uni_form', 'bootstrap3', 'foundation-5')

**Settings** file contains entries below (among others):

- `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'semantic-ui'`
- `INSTALLED_APPS = ('crispy_forms', 'semantic_ui')`

Here is the template code from **forumpost_create.html**:

```
{% extends 'forum/layouts/forum_main.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="ui main text container">
  <form action="" method="post" class="ui form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The error disappears when I use `form|crispy` in the **template**, but then the template is rendered unaffected, even when looking at the output HTML source, no changes whatsoever.

Code from **forms.py**

```
class ForumPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ForumPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Post body',
                'body'
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='ui primary button')
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = ForumPost
        fields = ['body']
```

How to make this to work? Is it because I am using *semantic-ui* and something needs to be done differently? (Majority of the tutorials I encounter prefer *bootstrap*).

Comment: I think this problem is due to internal validation of crispy forms. Try using https://github.com/alexey-grom/crispy-semantic-ui

Comment: This is exactly the page I followed when installing crispy.

Comment: Have you added 'semantic-ui' in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the initial post.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add semantic-ui into CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS in settings file

```
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = ('bootstrap', 'uni_form', 'bootstrap3', 'bootstrap4', 'semantic-ui')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Update Your `settings.py` File:**

   - Locate the `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK` setting and get its value.
   - Additionally, ensure that extact value from above variable is included within the tuple of `CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS` like so:

   ```py
   CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "Bootstrap5"
   CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = ("Bootstrap5",)
   ```

   If there are other template packs you wish to allow, you can include them in the tuple as well:

   ```py
   CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = ("Bootstrap4", "Bootstrap5", "uni_form")
   ```
2. **Adjust Your Template Code:**

   - Replace instances of `{{ form|crispy }}` with `{% crispy form %}` in your template files.

This setup ensures that your project is configured to use the Bootstrap 5 templates with django-crispy-forms, and the updated template tag is correctly rendering your forms.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer?